# HTML5 web sql: adding button to each row

Tags: sql, html, row

I have some script that is delivering a series of rows from an SQL database.

I want to append.() a button to each row. My current code is:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM myprogram', [], function (tx, results) {
                   var len = results.rows.length, i;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                        $('#myprog').append(results.rows.item(i).event)
                               $('.event').append('<button class="save_event">Remove</button>');

                        }
                });
```

But the buttons get doubled up. For example if I get 3 rows, the first row will have 3 buttons, the 2nd will have 2 and the last will have 1 button.

Can anyone help me out to have the buttons display only once per row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, quite simple:

```
var len = results.rows.length, i;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                        $('#myprog').append(results.rows.item(i).event).append('<button class="remove_event">Remove</button>');

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myprog').append(results.rows.item(i).event).append('<button class="remove_event">Remove</button>');
```

You need to append to `$('#myprog')` selector.

Comment: how do you mean cirius? #mrprog is the wrapper div that contains all the rows from the db so wouldnt it only append once?

Comment: No it won't. Because it is indexed with the `i` variable within the loop. The `i`th index will separate each button from the other.